# Show remote cursor on client that is connected to x11vnc server

Tags: x11vnc

x11vnc is running on the server, and

> vncviewer FullScreen=1 ViewOnly=1 UseLocalCursor=0 DotWhenNoCursor=1 computer0:5900

is being used to view the server's display on the client's display. The client's `vncviewer` is being provided by TigerVNC 1.3.1. The client shows everything that is on the server's display except the mouse cursor. I'm not sure whether to look for a setting to change on the client or the server, so I've been looking at both.

In the [x11vnc manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc) I found the `-cursor` option which I tried setting to `arrow`, but that didn't appear to have an effect.
For vncviewer I found the `UseLocalCursor` and `DotWhenNoCursor` options. I'm not sure whether either of them are relevant, but they don't seem to have had an effect either.

How can I make cursor movements on the server visible on the client? I don't much care about the appearance of the cursor on the client as long as it's visible.

Comment: Same question on different sites: [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176127) [2](https://superuser.com/q/811058) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34282363) [4](https://serverfault.com/q/454093)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had no luck with getting a cursor to show up in the `vncviewer` provided by TigerVNC 1.3.1, but the `vncviewer` from TightVNC 1.3.10 does show a cursor. Running

> x11vnc -cursor none -display :0

on the server and

> vncviewer -viewonly -fullscreen -x11cursor computer0:5900

on the client results in the position of the client's cursor being updated to reflect that of the server, which seems pretty optimal to me.